# How would I set the size of the detail and footer sections on Access continuous forms?

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access as a rapid proto-typing tool. Access allows me to make design changes in front of my clients. When I have continuous forms in Detail and Form Footer sections, the space between continuous forms opens and closes as the form resizes. It would be very useful to be able to specify the height that a continuous subform will occupy on a form.

The empty space (shown below) appears when the form is resized. This brings design meetings to a grinding halt. The empty space becomes the immediate focus of the meeting.

I am experimenting with VBA to try to fix the size of continuous subforms so that there is no empty space on the form.

I am also looking for any courses or books dedicated to the creation of quality UI in Access.

The problem that I am encountering is described below.

I have a Microsoft Access form with two linked continuous forms.

- The continuous form in the Detail section is the master form.
- The continuous form in the Footer section is th child form.

The Design View of the Continuous Form is shown below. The design view allows me to set the heights of an individual row. In form view, the height of the continuous forms vary with the number of rows in the data.  This opens and collapses empty and unused space on the forms.  This is confusing for the client.

- Ideally, I would like to fix the size of the Form programmatically with `Window.Height`
- Allocate the maximum sizes of the Detail and Footer section within the fixed Form size.
- This would be independent of the number of rows in the continuous form sections.

  [image: Design View of the Continuous Form]

My main question is how would I manage or remove the unused space between the Detail and Footer section in the Form view (shown below)?

- Are there settings that would allow me to set the height that a continuous form will take on a screen (regardless of the row count)?
- I am experimenting with approaches in VBA with very limited success.
- There is no way to move the child form in the Form Footer up while in Form View.
- Additionally, I don't want a UI that requires clients to constantly worry about form and control heights.

[image]

Comment: Form in Form view, not Design, drag bottom of form window up.

Comment: When the form is shown in Form View, the subform cannot be moved.  Is there any way to set a firm Top to the subform in the Form Footer section?

Comment: No, subform is not directly moved. Did not say to move subform. Move bottom of the main form.